# Dose any one can run imagej plugin by using jni?

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, imagej

Recently I am using java and maven dependency to run a program. At first, I used a jni file(libtensorflow_jni-1.7.0) during mvn compiling to generate jar plugin for imagej, and it works well. Then I changed jni dependency(libtensorflow_jni_gpu 1.12.0) in my pom.xml. After compiling, I trying to use the generated jar file in imagej, but the plugin failed( it used to work before i use that jni). There is no error message. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Please add more detail, did the build says Success? Are artifacts generated in target/ directories?

Comment: Thank you for replying! Yes, the build says success, and can run at ImageJ as plugin. Both can be generated as .jar file and run in ImageJ, but the second one fails during the processing.